# How can I get the last text in <p> through xpath in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I want to extract the text in the paragraph encircled in the screenshot. But from the last instance of the class, because this text is dynamic. Therefore I want the last text in this class.

I am tried  this

```
String Reply2= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='chat-message-content clearfix']/last[]")).getText(); ][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can't use last[]

use [last()]

```
//div[contains(@class,'chat-message-content')][last()]/p
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just need couple of changes in your xpath.

```
 String xPath = "(//div[@class='chat-message-content clearfix']/p)[last()]"
```

`//div[@class='chat-message-content clearfix']/p` should get all the `p` items under `chat-message-content clearfix` classes. Then group them by using <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd>. Now get the last item from the group using `[last()]`.

Get the text by using the below line.

```
 String Reply2= driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).getText();
```