# Getting the last text from a message in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, split, css-selectors

I want to access the the last text of a message that contains three numbers that will provide me accesses to a url. I've looked into this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592146/how-can-i-get-the-last-text-in-p-through-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver), but it's not helping.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="error_explanation">
  <h4>The form contains the following error:</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>
      "Validate branches Another open merge request already exist for this source branch: !323"
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I currently have

```
string sourcePath = ".//div[contains(text(),'Validate branches Another open')][last()]";
string urlPath    = driver.findElement(By.xpath(sourcePath)).getText();
driver.navigate.to(driver.getCurrentUrl()+urlPath);
```

But I am told that no element exist. I want to access the !323 and attach/navigate to the url

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text and strip the part **!323** to append it to the *url* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and then you can use `split()` using **positive look-ahead** by prefixing **`?=`** group on the pattern and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  String urlPath = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.alert.alert-danger#error_explanation>h4 +ul > li"))).getText();
  String[] parts = urlPath.split("(?=!)");
  driver.navigate.to(driver.getCurrentUrl()+parts[1]);
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  String urlPath = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-danger' and @id='error_explanation']//li[contains(., 'Validate branches Another open')]"))).getText();
  String[] parts = urlPath.split("(?=!)");
  driver.navigate.to(driver.getCurrentUrl()+parts[1]);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
 String myString= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Validate branches Another open')]").getText();
 myString=myString.substring(myString.indexOf("!")+1);
```

this will return 323